# how to compare lines read from a text file with integers passed in

Tags: java

I have the following method, which takes in an integer & string. In addition, i have to compare the parameters with what is read from a text file. I get the error 'incompatible types'. Do I have to do some parsing? If so, how? From what i understand, parsing is not required with readLine(). The ideas is that I have to scan a text file for a valid staffId & go to the next line to check the associated password as well.

```
public boolean staffExists (int staffid, String staffpwd) throws IOException
{
    boolean valid = false;      

    String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath + "/src/DBTextFiles/Administrator.txt"));

    try
    {                           
        String line = null;         
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
            {
                //System.out.println(line);

                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874621/how-to-compare-lines-read-from-a-text-file-with-integers-passed-in
                if (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid)) && (reader.readLine() == staffpwd))
                {
                    System.out.println ("Yes");
                    System.out.println ("Welcome " + reader.readLine() + "!");
                    valid = true;
                }                   
            }
        }               
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }                           
    finally
    {
        reader.close();
    }           
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: if i guess you have to get int and string separately

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this `if (line == staffid)`? Maybe we can offer a solution.

Comment: @peeskillet: I have edited it with (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid)). Parsing is achieved. Now the question is how do I go to the next line if the staffId entered is correct? As I need to check the password next.

Comment: @user2945412, use `if (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid)) && anotherCondition)`

Answer (score 3):

`line` is of type `String` and `staffid` is of type `int` . You cannot compare an `int` with a `String` as you are trying in the following line:

```
if (line == staffid)
```

You need to convert them to same datatype to do the comparison.

Convert your `staffid` int value to String using [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method and compare it with line using equals method.

```
if (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (line == staffid)
```

`line` is String `staffId` is `int`.

Comment: I have edited it with (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid)). Parsing is achieved. Now the question is how do I go to the next line of the text file if the staffId entered is correct? As I need to check the password next.

Comment: @user2945412, use `if (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid)) && anotherCondition)` to have two conditions that you need to check.

Comment: in that case, Ive done the following update to the method. Still it does not read the next line from the text file. Please kindly see edit.

Comment: @user2945412, DON'T compare `String`s with `==`. Use `equals()`

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you. So i did the following & it worked :) - if (line.equals(String.valueOf(staffid)) && (reader.readLine().equals(staffpwd)))

Comment: so sorry if i have been so vague. I guess i have to move on to other problems for now :)

Answer (score 0):

For String use `equals` method instead of `==`.

`==` compare references only.